# Application replacement advise (Internet Download Manager)

Tags: paid-applications

I've been using Ubuntu for some time now, and very pleased with the result. I'm just trying to replace the last of my application I had on Windows. The application is named "Internet Download Manager" and is basically a plugin in a browser, with a supporting application on the desktop that can download media elements from any page. Much like all the YouTube downloader apps that are out there, but way more options and sites.

I was wondering if anyone could recommend anything alike on Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ffmpeg` is good for this but it's command line only

Comment: I'll go check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Jdownloader2 is not a browser extension but it works quite well for me.   [snap install jdownloader2]

Answer (score 0):

There is such an [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/download-addon/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) for the browser firefox .
For other browsers I don't know
You can also download files from the page through the f12 button, and then clicking on "network" (in firefox) or on "sources" (in chrome), and there you can look for the files you need

Comment: I'll go and give it a try! Thanks for the advise, appreciate it.